# c++ inline поле

Tags: c++, ndk

сейчас я пишу так.
в .h файле

```
class CAdminRecon {
    static jobject   thiz;
}
```

в cpp файле

```
jobject   CAdminRecon::thiz        = nullptr;
```

Могу ли я писать вместо этого только в .h файле?

```
class CAdminRecon {
    static inline jobject   thiz = nullptr;
}
```

Т.е. физически да могу, всё на первый взгляд работает. Но может быть есть какие-то подводные камни?
Стоит так же уточнить что происходит все это в Android NDK

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work